# Running Python scripts (with parameters) within another Python script with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, serious-application-error

A common coding pattern used in AML was to run an AML (with parameters) inside another AML.

An application that I'm currently developing would benefit from being able to run a Python script (with parameters) within another Python script.

However, this does not seem to be at all straightforward.

Using ArcGIS 10, I'm experimenting with wrapping the "inner" Python script into an ArcGIS tool that has the parameters.  I thought it would be a simple matter to have the "outer" Python script use arcpy.ImportToolbox to import the toolbox and then run the tool(s) within it.  However, in testing so far all my attempts to run the "inner" tool from the "outer" script appear to simply skip the "inner" tool (no error is thrown).

Here is some test code to try and illustrate better what I am trying to describe.

My testinner.py script is:

```
inputString = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

newFC = "C:\\Temp\\test.gdb\\" + inputString
arcpy.Copy_management("C:\\Temp\\test.gdb\\test",newFC)
```

My testouter.py script is:

```
import arcpy

inputString1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
inputString2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

arcpy.ImportToolbox("C:\\Temp\\test.tbx")

arcpy.testinner_test(inputString1)

arcpy.testinner_test(inputString2)
```

For testinner.py its tool needs a single String parameter.

For testouter.py its tool needs two String parameters

The two tools are placed in a test.tbx.

The test.gdb just needs a single empty feature class called test.

Once you have the above assembled, running the testinner tool with a string like 'abc' passed in as its parameter should result in feature class 'test' being copied to one called 'abc' OK.

But when you try running the testouter tool with two strings like 'uvw' and 'xyz' as its parameters, the testinner tool within testouter.py seems to run OK once, but sends ArcMap 10 SP2 on Vista SP2 to a Serious Application Error when trying to use it the second time.

The same test using Windows XP SP3 and ArcGIS Desktop 10 SP2 also produces a Serious Application Error at the same point.

Comment: Going with @Dan's answer on this... don't think of .py files just as "scripts", think of them as modules you can reuse and recycle by importing the functions and classes you need from those modules. Abstract away those nested GP parameters by using one script to read in one set of parameters and then call functions in your other modules as needed. Use the [if __name__=='__main__'](http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/geoprocessing/archive/2008/12/01/Tips-and-tricks-_2D00_-Error-handling-in-Python-script-tools.aspx#5872) trick to make your modules both importable and still useable standalone.

Comment: I have Dan's example working to output: 

C:\Temp\Main_program.py
('sum some numbers: ', 55)
('sum of squares: ', 385)
('hello from 8: ', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

but am struggling to adapt it to an ArcPy example like I gave above.  Any further help on what an ArcPy example would look like would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See the answer I added -- should help explain things in the context of your example better.

Comment: I just came across an excellent blog post from Jason Pardy that provides an ArcPy template incorporating the coding pattern for Python modules at http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/geoprocessing/archive/2011/07/21/PythonTemplate.aspx

Comment: this link has since moved, and I believe it rests here now:
http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/08/04/pythontemplate/

Comment: @PolyGeo / others, forgive my lack of ArcPy awareness but is it possible to clarify how this is supposed to work. The `if __name__ == '__main__':` line fails for me with `Dataset c:\temp\test.gdb\test does not exist or is not supported`. Is it necessary to create test.gdb seperately first?

Comment: @geothery Yes - this example assumes that there is a pre-existing C:\Temp\test.gdb with a feature class called test but you could change this to any geodatabase and feature class you already have if you do not want to create them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is your test example modified to import a "utility" module within the main script and call a function using the parameters read in by the script tool:

---

**CopyFeaturesTool.py** - Script tool that reads in parameters and calls a function in another module

```
import CopyFeaturesUtility
import arcpy

inputFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
outputFCName = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
CopyFeaturesUtility.copyFeaturesToTempGDB(inputFC, outputFCName)
```

---

**CopyFeaturesUtility.py** - Module that has a single function `copyFeaturesToTempGDB`. Can either be imported or run standalone. If run standalone the code under `if __name__ == '__main__'` is run.

```
import arcpy
import os

def copyFeaturesToTempGDB(inputFeatures, outputName):
    """Copies the input features to a temporary file geodatabase.
    inputFeatures: The input feature class or layer.
    outputName: The name to give the output feature class."""

    tempGDB = r"c:\temp\test.gdb"
    newFC = os.path.join(tempGDB, outputName)
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(inputFeatures, newFC)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inputFC = r"c:\temp\test.gdb\test"
    outputFCName = "testCopy"
    copyFeaturesToTempGDB(inputFC, outputFCName)
```

---

I think you'll find this modular approach to be much more efficient and logical once you've gotten used to it. The [Modules section in the standard Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/tutorial/modules.html) is also a good resource for understanding how importing works.

For more arcpy-specific examples take a look at the built-in scripts in your `C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\ArcToolbox\Scripts` folder.

Answer (score 13):

You can accomplish this by importing a module (ie script) into your main script and calling its functions.  A simple demo is contained in the accompanying two scripts.

```
    '''
Main_program.py

demonstrates how to import and call functions from another module
'''
import sys
import CallingFunctions

a_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print sys.argv[0]
print CallingFunctions.func1(a_list)
print CallingFunctions.func5(a_list)
print CallingFunctions.func8(a_list)
```

for the main program and for the functions that are getting called

```
'''
Callingfunctions.py

imported into another program giving it access to the functions
'''

def func1(inputs=None):
  x = sum(inputs)
  return "sum some numbers: ", x
'''
more functions
'''
def func5(inputs=None):
  x_sq = 0
  for x in inputs:
    x_sq += x**2
  return "sum of squares: ", x_sq
'''
more functions
'''
def func8(inputs=None):
  return "hello from 8: ", inputs

'''
more functions
'''
if __name__ == "__main__":
  a_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
  inputs = "test inputs"
  a_dict = {1:[func1([1,2,3]) ],
            5:[func5([1,2,3])],
            8:[func8("inputs to 8")]}
  needed = [1,5,8]
  for akey in needed:
    if akey in a_list:
      action = a_dict[akey]
      print "\naction: ", action
```

you just have to ensure that the main module and the child module are in the same folder.  You can pass parameters to the child module easily and if the child module needs access to arcpy (assuming you are using version 10 of arcmap) simply pass a reference to it.

Answer (score 6):

Importing and running a function is the cleaner way to do it, but for the sake of completeness, there is also the `execfile` built-in function ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile)) which will let you run an arbitrary file in the current context.

Answer (score 0):

The [execfile method described by @JasonScheirer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/11361/115) allowed me to rearrange my code to that below and provides a solution to my test problem:

```
import arcpy

inputString1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
inputString2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

arcpy.ImportToolbox("H:/Temp/test.tbx")

# Write second Python script to an ASCII file for first parameter & execute it
f = open("H:/Temp/string1.py","w")
f.write('newFC = "H:/Temp/test.gdb/' + inputString1 + '"' + "\n")
f.write('arcpy.Copy_management("H:/Temp/test.gdb/test"' + ',newFC)')
f.close()
execfile("H:/Temp/string1.py")

# Write third Python script to an ASCII file for second parameter & execute it
f = open("H:/Temp/string2.py","w")
f.write('newFC = "H:/Temp/test.gdb/' + inputString2 + '"' + "\n")
f.write('arcpy.Copy_management("H:/Temp/test.gdb/test"' + ',newFC)')
f.close()
execfile("H:/Temp/string2.py")
```

However, this may prove cumbersome when applied to non-test script(s) which are much longer so I used [@blah238's work](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/11422/115) that endorsed [@DanPatterson's approach](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/11346/115) and came up with the following final (test) code that does exactly what I need.

```
# CopyFeaturesTool.py

import CopyFeaturesUtility
import arcpy
outputFCName = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
outputFCName2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

CopyFeaturesUtility.copyFeaturesToTempGDB("C:\\Temp\\test.gdb\\test", outputFCName)
CopyFeaturesUtility.copyFeaturesToTempGDB("C:\\Temp\\test.gdb\\test", outputFCName2)
```

and

```
# CopyFeaturesUtility.py

import arcpy
import os

def copyFeaturesToTempGDB(inputFeatures, outputName):
    """Copies the input features to a temporary file geodatabase.
    inputFeatures: The input feature class or layer.
    outputName: The name to give the output feature class."""

    tempGDB = r"C:\Temp\test.gdb"
    newFC = os.path.join(tempGDB, outputName)
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    arcpy.Copy_management(inputFeatures, newFC)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inputFC = r"C:\Temp\test.gdb\test"
    outputFCName = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    copyFeaturesToTempGDB(inputFC, outputFCName)
```