# Get text from user with pythonaddin

Tags: arcgis-10.4, python-addin, combo-box

I'm trying to figure out the best way to get text input from a user through a pythonaddin. After watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S78v_NH4tO0) it appears that a editable combo box is an option, but it's maybe not ideal due to its size. [Message boxes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/python-addins/the-pythonaddins-module.htm) only allow for Yes/No/Cancel so that's no good. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the editable combo box, upon further investigation, is a good way to go to get short text inputs from users.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found to give you this type of functionality is to create a script tool, and reference it from within the addin.py.  This will require you to create and reference a .TBX and .PY file.  The external script should then pass whatever you need back to the addin.  Use [pythonaddins.GPToolDialog()](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/python-addins/the-pythonaddins-module.htm) to kick off the external script.

Check out [blah238's response](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/11422/18981).